# Angular JS event called whenever anything is selected?

Tags: html, angularjs

I am using a select tag in a webpage. I am controlling it using Angular JS. I want a function to run whenever a value is selected. I know about the ng-change event but that only works for a change in value. What can I do?

```
<select class="form-control"
         ng-model="types" 
         ng-options="x.id as x.name for x in records" 
         ng-change="genres=undefined; events=undefined; clearDetails()" > 
</select>

<select class="form-control" 
        ng-change="events=undefined; clearDetails()" 
        ng-model="genres" 
        ng-options="x.id as x.name for x in records[types-1]['genre']" 
        ng-change="currentgenre=records[types-1]['genre'][genre-1][intro]" >
</select>

<select class="form-control" 
        ng-change="clearDetails(); loadEventData()" 
        ng-model="events" 
        ng-options="x.event_id as x.name for x in records[types-1]['genre'][genres-1]['details']" >
</select>
```

Comment: Good story but where is a code? please post problematic part and better try to reproduce in  in some Fiddle, Punker

Comment: `ng-change` twice or spell issue?

Comment: that's a bug :( but won't help the cause

Comment: question doesn't make sense... how can a value be `selected` and not trigger `ng-change`?

Comment: you select option A and re-select option A.

Comment: you have too much logic in html - try to move all ng-options handlers into functions of controller. for select and reselect use ng-click

Comment: there is no event for selecting same option except when `<select>` is `multiple`....and no values get changed either. So last comment really doesn't make sense. Please provide a proper problem description for this whole question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can (and should) be handled in your controller, and you can do it easily by watching the variable that is changing.  In this case that's `genres`, so you can do something like:

```
$scope.$watch('genres', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    $scope.events = undefined;
    clearDetails();
    ...
});
```

And you can make it even more specific by using `newValue` and `oldValue` to only run certain methods in certain cases, if you so desire.

Answer (score 0):

@OZ_ gave me the right answer in the comments section. `ng-click` was what I needed.